# Can I log work on JIRA issue with status "Closed"?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

Can I log work on an issue with status "Closed"?  I am in the Sprint "Agile" area, and dragged a few issues from "In Progress" to "Done".  I forgot to actually log the hours worked, expecting the "estimated" time to just propagate to "logged work".
Re-opening the issues is cumbersome and creates an unnecessary trail of notifications.

Comment: This is not coding question. Atlassian has its own forum and FAQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To allow issue-editing while the issue is closed:**

Go to the project `Workflows` screen and download it as and XML file.

Then edit the XML file and in the `Closed` step:

```
    <step id="6" name="Closed">
      <meta name="jira.status.id">6</meta>
      <meta name="jira.issue.editable">false</meta>
      <actions>
        <common-action id="3" />
      </actions>
    </step>
```

change

```
<meta name="jira.issue.editable">false</meta>
```

to

```
<meta name="jira.issue.editable">true</meta>
```

You can also mark or remove this line, but it's helpful to keep it for future needs.

Lastly, upload the edited workflow back to Jira.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Also the JIRA admin UI will let you update this value in the browser and publish without the XML step.

Comment: Hi, out of curiosity I am asking this question. Does it make sense to log work in JIRA once it is closed? - I mean is this looked at as some sort of violation of the workflow.

Answer (score 4):

You can even skip the "export to xml" part. In the workflow edit screen you can directly click on the gear-icon that appears when hovering over the "closed" status and thick the "Issue editable" flag.

Note that you have to have a custom workflow for this, since the JIRA default workflow is not editable.

Comment: For clarity, here is an axample URL to get to this setting for the Closed status (ID: 6 by default I think): https://jira.DOMAIN.com/secure/admin/workflows/ViewWorkflowStepMetaAttributes.jspa?workflowMode=draft&workflowName=PROJECT+WORFLOW+NAME&workflowStep=6