# How can I make a JIRA sub-task read-only?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I want to make a sub-task read-only when its parent is Closed. The sub-task does not have a typical workflow associated with it - just a single step that says "Not Applicable".

My thinking was that I'd extend the Closed action (whatever that is) and set the jira.issue.editable property to false. Is this possible, and if so, with what parts of the API??

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do so would be to attack a post function to the close transition of the parent issue that will move the sub-task to a locked transition.

To create the post function you can use [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) or [Jira Scripting Suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.quisapps.jira.jss). To add a locked transition for the subtask, add a new state to it's workflow and on the workflow screen make it read only, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616975/can-i-log-work-on-jira-issue-with-status-closed/14628044#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616975/can-i-log-work-on-jira-issue-with-status-closed/14628044#14628044) for more details.

If you want to restore the sub-task status once an issue was re-opened, on the post-script that leads to `close` state of the parent issue, save to a subtask custom field it's current state before making the transition to locked. Then attach a post function to the parent issue `re-open` transition that will move the subtask back to it's original state, according to what's saved in the custom field.

Comment: Wasn't this same question asked on answers.atlassian.com a few days ago?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be even simpler than I thought. I extended SimpleWorkflowAction which gets invoked when an issue is moved to closed. At that time, I set the Status of any children to closed. Voila, problem solved.

And yes, I asked on Atlassian as well!